# Chain-level representability of simplicial cohomology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, group-cohomology, simplicial-stuff, classifying-spaces

There's a simple construction for a classifying space $K(G,1)$ of a finite group $G$ as an infinite simplicial complex consisting of one $i$-simplex for each possible simplicial $1$-cocycle restricted to the standard $i$-simplex. Such an $i$-cocycle is determined by associating group elements to the edges $(x,x+1)$ for $0\leq x<i$, which "span" the standard $i$-simplex.

If I'm not mistaken, this classifying space allows us to turn the one-to-one correspondence between cohomology classes $H^1(X, G)$ and homotopy classes $X\rightarrow K(G, 1)$ into a chain-level one-to-one correspondence between simplicial cocycles (on a fixed simplicial complex/combinatorial manifold) and simplical maps to the classifying space. As a result, we get explicit simplicial formulas for cohomology operations
$$H^1(-, G)\rightarrow H^j(-, H)$$
by pulling back $j$-cocycles on the classifying space. The result of the cohomology operation on an $j$-simplex is then determined by the value of the input $1$-cocycle on the (spanning) edges of the $j$-simplex.

**Question**: Does the above generalize to other $K(G, h)$ for $h>1$ and finite abelian $G$? In particular, do there exist simplicial local formulas for any cohomology operation $h\rightarrow j$ whose value on a $j$-simplex is determined by the $h$-cocycle on sub-simplices?

I found [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/61563/115363) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/72497/487705) answer which, if I understand correctly, imply that the construction of $K(G,1)$ generalizes straight-forwardly: $K(G, h)$ has one $i$-simplex for each simplicial $h$-cocycle restricted to the standard $i$-simplex. The boundary maps of $K(G, h)$ are just the restriction of the $h$-cocycle to sub-simplices. So I'm relatively hopeful that the concrete simplicial representability will also work for $h>1$, just want to make sure that I'm not oversimplifying things.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Dold–Kan correspondence?  The concrete construction of K(G,h) simply applies the Dold–Kan functor Γ to a chain complex quasi-isomorphic to G[h], e.g., G[h] itself.  The answer to your question as it is formulated is affirmative, since the Dold–Kan functor produces fibrant simplicial sets, so any cohomology operation is represented by a genuine map K(G,h)→K(G',h').